# Cheap way to reset weld?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi, weld

We have an application that uses weld-se for CDI.
For our JUnit tests, we fire up a new weld container using the following trick: [WeldJUnit4Runner](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/CreatingUnitTestsWithWeldAndJunit4)

Since we have a lot of tests, running them gets to take a long time every time Weld has to startup and initialize itself. Is there any way to "reset" weld, so that we can get a fresh WeldContainer without Weld having to re-scan the whole classpath every time?

Comment: The only solution would be to put your test in the same tests class. That's what we do when testing CDI with Arquillian

Comment: I would use CdiTestRunner (see http://deltaspike.apache.org/test-control.html ) It's just awesome!

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: simply stop your open contexts.

Detailed answer: a great and easy way of using the Weld Se for testing purposes (unit test) offers DeltaSpike project from Apache itself http://deltaspike.apache.org/.

Currently I'm also participating in the development of a open source project which offers you a convenient way of testing your Java EE App with all the container services directly in the unit test via a JUnit Runner. https://github.com/NeoMorpheus/BeanTest

Also have a look at [jglue.org/cdi-unit-user-guide/](http://jglue.org/cdi-unit-user-guide/)

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to sacrifice isolation for speed, have a look at the Weld Test Container of [Pax Exam](https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/PAXEXAM3/Pax+Exam).

This does not reset Weld between tests, but as long as all your tests are in the same library/project/Maven module, Weld gets started only once for the entire test suite.

See [Getting Started With CDI Tests](https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/PAXEXAM3/Getting+Started+with+CDI+Tests).